# Center-aligning a div with "position: fixed"

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<body>
<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Bucuresti</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sighisoara</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tuzla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Comorova-Neptun</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Maramures</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sinaia</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
body {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #5A1560;
    min-height: 100%;
}
ul.navigation {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #D3EC60;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

My page looks like below:

[image]

I think you've already guessed that the div at the bottom (the `ul.navigation`) should stay on the center of the page. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `left:0;right:0;` to `ul.navigation`.